# Using CSOM, can I fetch RoleDefinitionBindings for all items in a list in a single query?

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, csom, .net

I know I'm able to get RoleAssignments in my call to get a ListItemCollection, e.g.

`context.Load(items, x => x.Include(y => y.RoleAssignments));`

Is there a way to also load each RoleAssignments' RoleDefinitionBindings in the same call to the server? Can I extend the Includes in some way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That one should do it:

```
context.Load(items, iCol => iCol.Include(
                item => item.RoleAssignments,
                item => item.RoleAssignments.Include(ra => ra.RoleDefinitionBindings)));
```

Comment: Thanks, that's great and helps me to understand the `Include` method better too.

Comment: Hey @Evariste, is it possible to filter within the `Include` request, for example if I want only role assignments with a specific attribute value, can I include that within the lambda?

Comment: I don't think that's possible at request time. Even if you use a `Where` in the LINQ request, the filtering actually happens client-side, thus there's no improvment in doing it in the `Load` over doing it after getting the collection, with a classic `foreach` loop.

Comment: Thanks so much for that. You've been really helpful. Cheers